# Jenkins github plugin isn't triggering a build when I push commits to master

Tags: github, jenkins-plugins

Also, I have a warning under the `Build when a change is pushed to GitHub` checkbox:

> Hook for repo [redacted] on www.github.com failed to be registered or were removed. More info can be found on global manage page. This message will be dismissed if Jenkins receives a PING event from repo or repo will be ignored in global configuration.

What are some possible causes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The github jenkins plugins seems to fail at registering webhooks when given a github URL including a leading `www.`. Double-check the repository URL you gave to jenkins, under `Git` under `Source Code Management` in the project configuration. Make sure it's not a `www` URL:

Problematic:

```
https://www.github.com/YOUR/REPO.git
```

Seems to work:

```
https://github.com/YOUR/REPO.git
```

After making this change, you should see webhooks pointing to your Jenkins instance appear in your repo's settings.

(I think this is a bug in the plugin. `git clone` works fine with the URL containing `www`. Could also be a gotcha in github's API.)

Answer (score 0):

For me It was resolved by clicking manually on
jenkins global configuration -> github plugin -> the button 're-register hooks for all jobs'.
I don't know why jenkins lost the previous registered hooks though...